# Is it true that every map $S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^2$ is null homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it true that every map $S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^2$ is null homotopic? How do I tackle this kind of problem using homology and cohomology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take an open disk $D$ inside a chart of $S^1 \times S^1$, and quotient out it's complement $D^c$. That's a map $S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1/{D^c} \cong S^2$, which is not nullhomotopic because it has degree $1$ (hint: local degree formula).